# Use rxjs operators to wait until both requests complete at once

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

```
  public reloadUser(){
    this.reloadUserGating();
    return this.request.get(`${this.url}/`).pipe(tap(user => this.currentUserSubject.next(user)));
}
```

I need to make `reloadUser()` method wait until both requests complete and then emit the observable. But it should not be sequally - both at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you the syntax and return type of `forkjoin` in this context:

```
public reloadUser(): Observable<[ReturnType1, ReturnType2]>{
    const obs1: Observable<ReturnType1> = this.reloadUserGating();
    const obs2: Observable<ReturnType2> = this.request
      .get(`${this.url}/`)
      .pipe(tap((user) => this.currentUserSubject.next(user)));
    return forkJoin([obs1, obs2]);
}
```

`forkJoin` returns a new observable, where the result is an array containing the results of the other observables.

Note: `forkJoin` does require the Observables to *complete*, not just fire a value. `combineLatest` can be used if the observables don't complete.